# Does WCS support tiling and pyramids?

Tags: geoserver, ogc, wcs

Due to performance reasons, I would like to implement some short of tiling + pyramids in a WCS service.

I am not so familiar with WCS, so I was not able to figure out whether it is something supported by the OGC standard.

The use case is to have x/y/t time-series of GeoTiff data (often file sizes are in the scale of GiB), derived from satellite imagery exposed to my client application. I understand that some short of pyramid computation or tiling needs to be done prior to the ingestion in the WCS Server (e.g. GeoServer) for my use case.

Is WCS a feasible approach to implementing the use case described above?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to know. Do you mean if the source files on the WCS server can be tiled and with pyramids, or it is is possible to send tiled GeoTIFFs with pyramid layers as a response to GetCoverage?

Comment: My question is actually if it is possible to send tiled GeoTiffs with pyramid layers as a response to GetCoverage in a way that it's feasible for both frontend and backend sides to perform in order to deliver a good UX.

Therefore, I want to receive tiled GeoTIFFs with pyramid layers as a response to GetCoverage requests, that have been pre-computed at ingestion time by the WCS server being, thus, the source files of the WCS server.

I hope this clarifies the issue a bit more.

Comment: Strictly that's not a concern for the OGC WCS standard (input and output formats) just ways of requesting them.

Comment: Could scaling help